# In pysaml2, how does one include attributes in the initial AuthNResponse?

Tags: python, saml

I have the example IdP/SP working ok. I can hook up my app to the example IdP and the handshake works ok. However, the initial AuthNResponse includes only the eduPersonTargetedID and I want it to include other attibutes, like sn, email, etc. I know the response includes a link to the attribute service but I need the attributes in the AuthNResponse.

Any suggestions/pointers on how to accomplish that?

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a dict that maps keys of your to-be attributes to their values:

```py
IDENTITY = {"surName": ["Jeter"], "givenName": ["Derek"],"title": ["shortstop"]}
server.create_authn_response(IDENTITY,...); # other arguments are omitted for this example
```

Doing so yields this `<AttributeStatement>` in the emitted response:

```xml
<ns1:AttributeStatement>
                <ns1:Attribute FriendlyName="givenName" Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                    <ns1:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Derek</ns1:AttributeValue>
                </ns1:Attribute>
                <ns1:Attribute FriendlyName="surName" Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.4" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                    <ns1:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Jeter</ns1:AttributeValue>
                </ns1:Attribute>
                <ns1:Attribute FriendlyName="title" Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.12" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                    <ns1:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">shortstop</ns1:AttributeValue>
                </ns1:Attribute>
</ns1:AttributeStatement>
```

As you can see, `FriendlyName` of the `<Attribute>` element is set to the name of the key in `IDENTITY` dict. The value of `<AttributeValue>` element is set to the value of the corresponding dict entry based on the key. Each `<Attribute>` element also has `Name` and `NameFormat` attributes. Values of these come from a [configuration map](https://pysaml2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/config.html#attribute-map-dir) you also have to set up.

Configuration maps are files that are loaded from a directory pointed to by `attribute_map_dir` in the identity provider config file:

```py
CONFIG = {
    "entityid": "http://saml.example.com:saml/idp.xml",
    ...
    "attribute_map_dir": "attributemaps"
}
```

In the `attributemaps` directory, multiple files could exist. Each file is Python source with a MAP dict that has the SAML identifier (name) of the attribute format that your identity provider will support and `to` and `fro` nested maps. The `to` map is used by the identity provider to translate from the name of the (incoming) key in the `IDENTITY` dict to the value of (outgoing) `Name` attribute in `<AttributeValue>` element.

```
X500ATTR_OID = "urn:oid:2.5.4."

MAP = {
    "identifier": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri",
    "fro": {
        ...
    },
    "to": {
        'surName': X500ATTR_OID+'4',
        'givenName': X500ATTR_OID+'42',
         ...
        'title': X500ATTR_OID+'12'
    }
}
```

You can copy the maps from [pysaml2 source](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2/tree/master/example/attributemaps) and modify them as needed. The keys/values in `to` nested map and the value of `identifier` will be determined by what your SAML service provider expects/supports. `FriendlyName` doesn't matter, it's used for readability but the spec doesn't rely on it.